# RegEx to return first twelve of last thirteen digits?

Tags: .net, regex, grouping, regex-lookarounds

I'm working on this regex, and it's not functioning as I expected. Here is my regex thus far -- `.{12}(?=.)$|(^.{1,12}$)`

The first half, `.{12}(?=.)$` is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to match the first twelve of the last thirteen characters from an input string.

Examples:
`1234567890123` --> `123456789012`
`123456789012345` --> `345678901234`
`12345678901234567890` --> `890123456789`

It seems like the lookahead is failing for me. Using the demo of something like `q(?=w)` correctly matches a q followed by a w, but I can't get it to work in my specific instance.

Thanks!

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Can't you simply use grouping ? EDIT : just as proposed by Marc B

Comment: @fardjad - I'm testing it in Javascript (regexpal.com) but it will actually run in a .Net Environment. I should have mentioned that. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The look-ahead is zero-width so `(?=.)$` is a contradiction

```
.{12}(?=.$)|^.{1,12}$
```

Comment: I've also always wondered what they meant by Zero-Width.. Thanks again